# Is it possible to add a EUR Master Card in PayPal?

Tags: credit-card, paypal, mastercard

I have a bank account and two Master Cards with it: for USD and for EUR. I want to add EUR card in my PayPal account. Is it possible? Do PayPal accepts Euro or it will exchange Euro to US dollars?

Comment: I did that but I live in Europe, so your situation might be different.